# How to come back from child package to Parent package using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I am using parent child package in SSIS and I am able to go to child package and it executes the child package functionality. Now I need to come back to parent package and continue executing the tasks after where I called the child package.

For ex: If I have tasks like A-->B-->c (child package) -->D-->E, So after executing the task C,mwhich is child package, Flow should come back to Parent package and start executing from D. How can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste in screenshot of your parent package flow?

Comment: The inherit functionality of SSIS works as described. I have seen where the colors in Visual Studio don't turn green but still have run. You might want to check either the log or check if steps D & E actually did run.

Comment: Is there a breakpoint or a data viewer that hasn't been cleared from the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSIS tasks there is an *[Execute Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task?view=sql-server-ver15)* task which does exactly what you want. It starts the Child package, passing parameters you specified at Master package, executes it and returns control to Master package task execution.

Comment: yes, But in my case it is not coming back to Parent package's next task. Do I need to set any property?

Comment: Strange... @ramu, Could you add task flow screenshot from the Master package and execution log to your question.

Comment: Thanks Everyone....It was a silly mistake while making the connection. It is working now.